# How to get coverage for private init

Tags: swift, unit-testing, code-coverage, private

#### The context

In [a framework](https://github.com/JanNash/DjangoConsumer) I'm currently building, I am using multiple structs [(example)](https://github.com/JanNash/DjangoConsumer/blob/master/DjangoConsumer/Source/Core/Nodes/Node.swift#L161) to store String constants. Let's say one looked like this:

```
public struct SpecificConstants {
    private init() {}
    public static let foo: String = "foo"
}
```

This is all nice and well. You can use the constant, it doesn't clutter global namespace, the struct name states the specific purpose of the constants which are defined in it.

Also, by making `init()` private, it is made clear inside the framework (it's open source) and outside of it that this struct should not be instantiated. It wouldn't hurt if you were to create an instance of it but it would also have no use at all. Also, the init would show up in autocomplete if it weren't private, which would annoy me :)

#### The problem

I'm proudly writing a lot of tests for the framework and I'm using Xcode's internal coverage reporting (llvm cov). Unfortunately, this coverage reporting shows the init as 'not covered':

[image: screenshot of init not covered by tests]

This is completely logical, since the init isn't being run by the tests, because it can't be.
To my distress, this prevents me from getting the good ol' 100% coverage.

#### Possible solutions

1. I could use [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php), which would enable me to use `LCOV_EXCL_LINE` or `LCOV_EXCL_START` and `LCOV_EXCL_STOP` to exclude the inits from the coverage.
   *Why not:* I'd love not having to setup a different coverage tool when there's already a builtin tool in Xcode.
2. I could make the inits internally accessible so I could gain access to them inside my unit tests by importing the module as `@testable`.
   *Why not:* Though they would still be inaccessible from outside the framework, they would now be visible inside the framework, which I don't like. I'd like them to be darn private :D
3. I could live with my coverage never reaching 100%.
   *Why not:* Because I just can't :).

#### The question

Is there any way (I could live with it being a bit, even quite hacky) to run this forsaken init in my unit tests while keeping it inaccessible from outside as well as inside the framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your String constants to an enum then you won't need a private init.

```
enum SpecificConstants {
    static let foo = "foo"
}
```

Comment: I tried an enum with RawValue = String which leads to an ```init?(rawValue)``` with the same access level as the enum being synthesized.  Of course, I always keep forgetting that enums can have ```static let```s as well. Thanks, you made my day! :)